# Locate Sqllite Database on Android Phone

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, maui

Please suggest where I could locate MCQ.db3 an Sqlite database on Android Phone.

https://github.com/KalyanAllam/MauiAppMCQs

```
SQLiteAsyncConnection Database;
        private SQLiteAsyncConnection _dbConnection;
        public const string DatabaseFilename = "MCQ.db3";
        async Task Init()
        {  
        string dbPath  =
         Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, DatabaseFilename);
            _dbConnection = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbPath);
            if (Database is not null)
                return;
            Database = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbPath, Constants.Flags);
    
            var result = await Database.CreateTableAsync<InQuestion>();
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **MCQ.db3** will be created at the value of dbPath. And it's value is `/data/user/0/com.companyname.mauiappmcqs/files/MCQ.db3`. And you can also try to debug to check it.

In addition, only using `Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, DatabaseFilename);` will not create the file. You need to create the file by yourself. Such as:

```
string dbPath  =
         Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, DatabaseFilename);
FileStream fileStream = 
         new FileStream(dbPath , FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);
```

And then you will find the **MCQ.db3** in the `/data/user/0/com.companyname.mauiappmcqs/files` folder.

Comment: I connected my Samsung Phone  to PC, I could only see ,This path PC\Allam's Galaxy M02s\Phone\Android\data\com.companyname.mauiappmcqs, how do I locate /data/user/0/com.companyname.mauiappmcqs/files

Comment: Also I deployed MAUI App to Windows 10 where could I find The MCQ.db3

I searched in deployment folder

C:\Users\allam\destination\

Comment: Yes, the file with such path can't be found by the file manager. But I can find it with the Android Studio's  Device File Explorer. So you can download the android studio on your pc.@KALYANAALLAM

Comment: And if you want the file can be found in the file manager. You can use `Android.App.Application.Context.GetExternalFilesDir("").AbsolutePath` instead of the `FileSystem.AppDataDirectory` for the android. @KALYANAALLAM

Comment: Did you find the file by the Android Studio? @KALYANAALLAM

Comment: For now I am closing the case